# How to install and use new font which will be used in view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anybody know how to install some of my custom font into rails and use it in my application to show in view.html.erb (for example) so everybody can see text written in new font?

I am using rails 3

**EDIT:**

I see I have to correct myself. I use font `.ttf` as that is the only one I have found. if that makes any difference.

I would like to do that using classic `CSS` or with use of `HAML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder called `fonts` in `app/assets/` then move all your custom fonts there ([example](https://github.com/meurio/panela-de-pressao/tree/master/app/assets/fonts)).

Restart your server for the new assets to be available and create a stylesheet to declare your font-faces, for example `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css`, than write:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My Custom Font';
  src: font-url('mycustomfont-regular.eot');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

// bold
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My Custom Font';
  src: font-url('mycustomfont-bold.eot');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

// italic
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My Custom Font';
  src: font-url('mycustomfont-italic.eot');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

([example](https://github.com/meurio/panela-de-pressao/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/font.sass)).
Now you can setup your custom font using `font-family: "My Custom Font"`

Comment: can I use `ttf` file as well?

Comment: and third question, maybe I defined my font-family bad. How do I know which font family is it? I am using `Albertsthal_Typewriter.ttf`?

Comment: You can set any font-family name, chose one that make sense for you

Comment: You can use ttf format, but maybe you should declare that you are using this format, see this example: https://github.com/meurio/panela-de-pressao/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/font.sass

Comment: Does this apply when I use regular css or haml? Because I don't have @font-face there?

Comment: This is not HAML, this is SASS

Comment: I can see. Is there a way to do that the same in classic css or haml? I am updating the question.

Comment: I've changed my answer to CSS

Comment: Ok, I will try, and let you know

Comment: ok, I have returned to this answer. I have ended up by creating an image instead of using fonts. The main reason is that custom font is not broadly supported, and I couldn't get them working on ubuntu locally. It is supported on new browsers, but not all are using latest IE versions and other browsers. I haven't marked it as `answered` as I didn't make it to work on my machine, I gave only +1, but I believe it is a good approach,.Thanks for the effort

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't have EOT fonts, and the app was quite small so I could have created the images instead of fonts as well. So I used images :) even though that only 6.5% of the browsers don't support custom fonts, I decided to use images. Research based on http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp and http://www.statowl.com/web_browser_usage_by_version.php?limit%5B%5D=ie&...

Comment: @Aleks check this web font converter http://www.font2web.com/ you can generate all types of font

Comment: hmmm, looks interesting, I will give it a shot :) although I have finished what I wanted to finish, but I believe this will come in handy in the future. Thanks for the effort :) I will mark the answer as answered. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want Rails to render an image in a particular font that is then sent to the client, what you're looking for is [Web Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography#Web_fonts) where you specify in CSS how text should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS with this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: Sabon;
  src: asset-url('Sabon-Roman.otf', font);
}
```

and place your font in app/assets/fonts.

It works for OTF fonts.